# Google Chrome Extension: Notification System, RSS Reader

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, rss-reader

I've created a simple RSS Reader extension for my blog, however, I was wondering how I could implement a notification system (like Google Reader Notifier + Gmail Notifier have).
So, a little number would popup on the extension icon when a new post is available/unread.

How would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText) API.

Something like:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: '5' });
```

Comment: Will that number auto-update when the RSS feed does? (I'm using Google's Feedburner's BuzzBoost)

Comment: The number only changes when you call the setBadgeText method. If you poll for new updates you have to count how many new entries there are update the badge with the number.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not easy? Any ideas how to go about it or not?

Comment: Assuming you are already pulling in the feed it is pretty much just filtering the array of posts and getting the length of the remaining array.

Comment: You lost me, I guess I should leave this stuff to the professionals